# Perform loop while function return false until it return true (or fail)

Tags: php, function, loops, while-loop

How can i write this code with a loop ?

```
    $date = new DateTime;

    if(checkForDate($date->format('m')) == true) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        $date->sub(new DateInterval('P1M'));
        if(checkForDate($date->format('m')) == true) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            $date->sub(new DateInterval('P1M'));
            if(checkForDate($date->format('m')) == true) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                // Fail. 
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime;
if(multipleCheckDate($date) == true) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}


function multipleCheckDate($date, $i = 0) {
    if(checkDate() == true) {
        return true;
    }
    else if($i < 6) {
        $date->sub(new DateInterval('P1M'));    
        $i++;
        return $this->multipleCheckDate($date, $i);
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {

    $date->sub(new DateInterval('P1M'));
    if(checkForDate($date->format('m')) == true) {
        return true;
    }

}

return false;
```

As you please. But this approach doesn't really make sense. Probably you want something else.